# Ant Design Cannot find module 'rc-textarea'

Tags: reactjs, webpack, antd, yarnpkg, ant-design-pro

I just created an Umi Ant Design Pro project but when i run my project (yarn start),i am getting the following error:

[image: rc-textarea error]

Steps taken to resolve this issue:

1:installed rc-textarea:

```
yarn add rc-textarea
```

2:stopped my server and ran yarn again in my terminal

3:then ran yarn start to start my server and still got the same error although my terminal this time stopped displaying the error i keep getting in my browser as seen below:

[image: My Terminal]

Step4:I then did some Research and came across this link
[Git Memory Blog](https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/ant-design/ant-design/25285/651065034)
But the path : ./node_modules/antd/es/input/TextArea.js does not exist in my project.

[image: Unable to find path]
[image: Unable to find path2]

I also found a github link with a similar issue:
[GithubIssue](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/26718)

Other solutions did not work so i tried  wbcs's solution:

```
yarn cache clean
yarn install
```

But the error is still eminent.
My inspection window indicates that this is a possible webpack issue:

[image: InspectWindow]

How do i resolve this?

Comment: I managed to get the project to run by reinstalling antd umi,now just dealing with this error:Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Comment: where do you get error Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0?

Comment: @arminyahya The error was coming from one of the json files in the node_modules.I did not dig in to identify the file.I simply cleaned my cache again with yarn,deleted the node_modules folder and performed another installation of the dependencies- yarn or npm i.In my case,i am using yarn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing `.umi` and `node_modules` folders, and then start this project again.

Comment: Yes,this eventually worked for me. Thanks